# Better Way To Authenticate than LogonUser()

Tags: windows, authentication, credential-providers

For years we have been using LogonUser() to authenticate windows credentials, as it works for both local and domain accounts. I understand this is not its true intended purpose and it is a very slow process. Is anyone else aware of a faster "catch all" way to test a set of windows credentials (name, password, domain) than LogonUser() that functions in all scenarios (local and domain accounts)?

EDIT:
Upon further review the delay was caused by authentication to a local machine using the work group rather than the machine name.